# why does this angularjs case statement excute only once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switch-statement, case

I have a function in my controller that costs an item based on a old unit and new unit value. When the user changes the unit option a ng-change calls $scope.cost

```
$scope.cost = function(oldunit, newunit) {

   var x = 0;        

   switch(newunit)
   {

      case 'Kilograms':
         if(oldunit=='Pounds'){
            x = 1;
         }

         break;

      case 'Pounds':
         if(oldunit=='Kilograms'){
            x = 2;
         }

         break;
    }

    return x;    
}
```

The view contains a list of items which call $scope.cost. Only the first iteration of the class works, and subsequently the following iterations return 0.

Is there a better way or place for running such functionality with angularjs? Secondly, Why is the switch statement only running once?

Comment: Post the code calling `$scope.cost`. Better still - post a fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: Use $watch in your wrapped function since a user is changing a value.